# ssh: connect to host port 22: Connection refused

Tags: fedora, scp, macos

I am on Mac OS and trying to send a directory to a fedora linux laptop, using the command sudo scp -r send_folder user@ip:/, but I get the error:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.107 port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
```

SSH is already open and running on the fedora computer, I've checked through nmap, I also have file sharing enabled on my mac. How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried `ssh user@ip` to check it works - as for `file sharing` - not required for this

Comment: Yes, it still gives the same error.

Comment: What's strange is that I can ssh from my fedora machine into my mac, but not vice versa.

Comment: perhaps there's a firewall on the fedora